# Error during Wordpress Plugin activation

Tags: php, wordpress

Got the following error during the plugin activation

The plugin generated 1 character of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

here is the code of that plugin
http://pastebin.com/ZKrKQbPv

Also i can't able to edit plugin content via wordpress plugin editor. When i click save it shows “headers already sent” error.

Comment: can you post the output of one.php and two.php?

Comment: I haven't created those file. Both are empty php files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure **BOTH** one.php and two.php contain **ONLY** the following code if keeping blank:

```
<?php
```

Place that at the very top of the files and save and upload them to server. By including them as they are blank they have a newline \n in them which is being output. This will fix it. **DO  NOT** put a closing ?> tag. It's recommended you don't end your files with them since it increases the likelihood as well of putting newlines by accident.

Comment: oh thanks it's solved. I also deleted the ?> in index file.